# Recommended method for targets spawning multiple processes in Makefile

Tags: makefile

What is the recommended approach for writing makefile that has target recipes that spawn multiple processes? Please consider this example.

I have my Makefile as follows:

```
all: run1 run2 run3

run%: 
        <invoke script that spawns multiple processes>
```

Consider that I have a system with 4 cores. Consider that recipe for run1 creates 1 process, run2 creates 2 process, and run3 creates 3 processes. There are some IO intensive processes and some are CPU intensive processes. Also, I would like to enable parallelism with make.

What is the recommended approach of figuring out the number of jobs to use for make file? If I use 4, one of the processes may be starved of CPU. If I use a lesser number of jobs, I may end up not utilizing my CPU efficiently.

Is there an option in Makefile to handle targets that spawn multiple processes? Is there an option in make that suggests the make process to consider a target as 2 jobs rather than 1?

Comment: In conjunction with `--jobs` you might also want to consider the [`--max-load`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002d_002dmax_002dload) option to prevent too many jobs being started.

Comment: Are you willing to split the 3-process script into three 1-process scrips, put each in a different rule, and have those three targets as prerequisites of a master rule (that does nothing)? Make can handle multiple processes.

Comment: Yes. Using max load is an okay option here. I was looking for something that can give me more control.

Comment: I do not want to split my script to multiple parts